# set the application as default application

Tags: android, sms, default

how can i make my application the default application, is there anyway to ask the user if he want to set my application as default application when he want to install it on the mobile?, if not is there any other way to do it?
ps. I'm developing Messaging application Using android 2.3
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just state in  the manifest file that the application is capable of receiving messages of a given type (or anything else) and after your app has been installed, Android will automatically display a dialog box when a message of the very same type is received. The dialog box will contain a list of all the apps installed which are capable of handling the given message. The user then have the option to make one of those applications as default for handling messages of given type.

Comment: thanks for your replay,just to make sure, i just have to mention in the permission that my application send and receive SMS's?

Comment: yes but you also have to specify a filter for the data type, you might want to take a look at the source code of the default Android Message application

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure your application registers an interest in handling message intents, this way when one is launched and Android prompts the user which application to use for SMS they can select your application, the "use by default" is a checkbox on the selection dialog.

I'm not sure if this is uniform across all devices as some OEM's have their own spin on some of the functionality, but its included in stock android as well as HTC Sense.

To register an interest you need to look at the android service documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: thanks for your replay, i'll read it and implement it and give you my feedback.